# Reading a plist dictionary

Tags: uitableview, plist, nsdictionary

I am stuck trying to figure out how this works. I have a plist that is an array of dictionaries. I need to read each dictionary separately within the array and map each dictionary to cells in a tableview. I have a feeling this is extremely simple, but I am not having success accessing the first dictionary and writing each key/value pair to a tableview; then in response to 'next' button, writing 2nd dictionary to tavbeview, then 3rd dictionary, etc. etc. I don't have to go backward, but I do have to go forward displaying contents of each successive dictionary in tableview.
Any tips/code samples will to be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
NSDictionary *cellValue = [self.array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSString *label = [cellValue objectForKey:@"label"];
[cell.textLabel setText:label];
```

The `array` is initialized with the contents of an `plist`. The `plist` has a dictionary with a key called `label` which can then be accessed through `objectForKey`.

I am not exactly sure what you are doing for writing your dictionaries, but what I did was create a custom class called `DataObject` added I few methods like `addNewItem` and `writeToFile` like this:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *finalPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileTitle];

[array writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
```

and for `addNewItem:(NSString *)label`:

```
NSDictionary *newItem = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:label,@"label", nil];
[array addObject:newItem];
[newItem release];
[self writeTask];
```

Then simply access them like this:

```
DataObject *db = [[DataObject alloc] init];
[db addNewItem:youItemTitle];
[db release];
```

although this would be very bad for memory management.